# How to Create Pattern for Textbox?

Tags: html, design-patterns

I have Textbox and I want to Allow Numeric value or Only Letter 'A'.
Which Pattern will prefer for this?

```
<input type="text" id="txt" name="txt" pattern="^[0-9][A]*$" title="Allow numeric value or only Letter 'A'" required>
```

Comment: I use this `pattern="^[0-9]*$|[A]"`, is this right?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
<input type="text" id="txt" name="txt" pattern="[\dA]*" title="Allow numeric value or only Letter 'A'" required>
```

This is good place to [learn Regex](https://regexone.com/lesson/introduction_abcs)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this regex -  "^([0-9]{1,})|(A)$"
Basically means either allow numerical value of any length ({1,}) or just A

```
<input type="text" id="txt" name="txt" pattern="^([0-9]{1,})|(A)$" title="Allow numeric value or only Letter 'A'" required>
```

Your regex meant allow one [0-9] value and 0 to any occurrences of A. So it would match patterns like - 0, 1A, 1AA etc.